# Elasticsearch - Unable to create point in time

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm unable to create a point in time (trying through Kibana).

When sending the following request:

`POST test_index/_pit?keep_alive=1m`

I get the response:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parse_exception",
        "reason" : "request body is required"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parse_exception",
    "reason" : "request body is required"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I tried adding an empty body just in case and got:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "request [/test_index/_pit] contains unrecognized parameter: [keep_alive]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "request [/test_index/_pit] contains unrecognized parameter: [keep_alive]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I'm using version 7.10.2 of Elasticsearch and the point in time was introduced in 7.10.0.

Comment: Which elasticsearch distribution are you using?

Comment: Could it be the reason? https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/65906 Point in time was an XPack feature back in the days

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

I'm using AWS (OpenSearch) and apparently there "edition" of Elasticsearch 7.10 doesn't include PIT.

I'll have to upgrade to OpenSearch 2.5 or above in order to use PIT.

[Features by engine version in Amazon OpenSearch Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/features-by-version.html)